# How to maintain the radius of container in flutter , when the size of the container starts to increase?

Tags: flutter, dart

The radius is same but they look different due to size. The effect of radius diminishes (it flattens, become more of a square ) as the size increases

[image]

Comment: set a radius = 1000 for example, it will have always rounded corners

Comment: @someuser yes but I dont want that big radius (I need a smaller curvature)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be using `LayoutBuilder`, to get the width of the `Widget`.

Follows an example:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          width: 555,
          height: 155,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(constraints.maxWidth), // always rounded
          ));
    }),
  );
}
```